# How do I construct a Bitcoin transaction with the Bitcoin Core Console?

Tags: mining-reward

How do I create a transaction using the debug console of Bitcoin Core v0.15.1 (64-bit)?

I have been able to use the commands to create addresses. I figured out how to create, sign, and send a raw transaction. However when I try to send the transaction, I get an erro saying that my fee is too low.

Am I getting this error because I'm resetting the console before I start my commands ? Should I let my console time add up or reset it before a transaction ?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I getting this error because I'm resetting the console before I start my commands ? Should I let my console time add up or reset it before a transaction ?

No, that is completely unrelated.

The transaction fee in a transaction is determined by the difference between the sum of the values of the outputs and the sum of the values of the inputs. Bitcoin Core will not accept a transaction which has a fee rate (in BTC/virtual-kilobyte) that is too low. You probably aren't setting a transaction fee or are setting one that is too low. To set a transaction fee, you need to decrease the values of your outputs so that the difference is larger.